# Getting gibberish instead of numbers using memcpy and strtoul

Tags: c, string, char, memcpy, strtol

I have the following piece of code compiling under gcc:

```
int parseMsg(const char *msg_to_parse, unsigned long *exp_input, unsigned long *sysTicks )
{
   int l_msg_size = strlen(msg_to_parse);
   if(l_msg_size <10)
          return -1;
    char l_exp_input_arr[10];
    char l_sys_ticks_arr[10];
    memcpy(l_sys_ticks_arr,msg_to_parse+12,10);

    memcpy(l_exp_input_arr,msg_to_parse,10);
   //l_msg_size = strlen(msg_to_parse);
    *sysTicks = strtoul(l_sys_ticks_arr,NULL,10);

   *exp_input = strtoul(l_exp_input_arr,NULL,10);



   return 0;
}
```

And I'm trying to test it in the following manner:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int parseMsg(const char *msg_to_parse, unsigned long *exp_input, unsigned long *sysTicks );

int main(void) {
char msg[] = "1234567890  59876543213";
unsigned long along1, along2;
along1 =0;
along2=0;
parseMsg(msg,&along1, &along2 );
printf("result of parsing: \n \t Along 1 is %lu \n \t Along 2 is %lu \n",along1, along2);
return 0;
}
```

But, I'm getting the following result:

result of parsing: 
     Along 1 is 1234567890 
     Along 2 is 4294967295

Why is the second unsigned long wrong?

Thanks

Comment: because you aren't null terminating the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second integer you provide is too big to be represented in memory on your architecture. So, according to its API, *strtoul* is just returning you ULONG_MAX (=4294967295 on your architecture), along with setting *errno* to *ERANGE*

strtoul API is here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/

**BUT** it may also fail if you gave a smaller integer, because *strtoul* only stops parsing when it encounters a non-numerical character. Since you didn't ensure that, you cannot be sure that *strtoul* will not try to parse whatever is in memory just after your strings. (So assuming random, you have 10 chance out of 256 to have a conversion error)

Terminate your strings with \0, it will be ok then :

```
char l_exp_input_arr[11]; // +1 for \0
char l_sys_ticks_arr[11];

memcpy(l_sys_ticks_arr, msg_to_parse+12, 10);
l_sys_ticks_arr[10] = '\0';

memcpy(l_exp_input_arr, msg_to_parse, 10);
l_exp_input_arr[10] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your two temporary char[] variables one char longer and then make the last character NULL.